# Anyone know what could cause this pattern of http requests?

Tags: web-server, http, httpd

It's from a registered user on my website.

Activity begins with normal looking URLs, which correlates to manual browsing, but then that stops.

After that I get the same GUID-based requests every 3 seconds for hours.

I suspect it's some sort of 'auto-refresh' tool, or maybe some tool to see if a page has changed, but since it's requesting an invalid URL that doesn't make much sense.

Note that the URL being requested actually includes the `from HTTP/1.1` bit, which clearly isn't valid and so my server rightly returns a 404.

Any malfunctioning browser extension or software you know of with this pattern?

```
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6300 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6394 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6258 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6377 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6436 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6449 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
GET /A4266F87-1E33-D746-A1DF-306C1E797113/183D2B68-3890-E646-81A7-F0D75019F7FF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 6175 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: it could be malware or other such malicious software testing an exploit on your server

Comment: I cant 100% rule out malware, but it doesn't seem indicative of malware imo. The url is the same each time, and clearly invalid. I don't know what info the malware would possibly hope to gain by this, especially as it runs every 3 seconds for very long periods. I think its more likely some web extension or auto-refresh tool, but none of it makes much sense to me

Comment: It's just that one user? Have him try disabling browser extensions and see if it stops this.

Comment: @Barmar its a great idea but unfortunately my users are typically 'mature', and really not very technical. Trying to persuade them to disable browser extensions or anything of that nature would probably be met with suspicion, as they just have zero understanding of the reasons behind me asking.

Comment: If the problem is at the user's end, you'll eventually have to deal with them to fix their configuration. "Your computer is sending some strange messages to the server, I think it's because of one of the browser plugin. I'd like to work with you to figure out which one it is."

Comment: Its a free website, so I actually 'fixed' it by firewalling them :-) I was just curious about what could cause this pattern of traffic, as it seems highly unusual